# Apache Pig Load data with comma and space (How can I do?)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is my question:
I wonder know how to load these data:

Input data:
18 (John, Mary)
22 (Austin, Sunny)
78 (Richard, Alice)
87 (Johnny,)

And I want load these data to the variable A

So I write this:

`A = Load 'data' AS (age:int, couple:(husband:chararray, wife:chararray));`

But when I Dumped A the result give me like this:
(,)
(,)
(,)
(,)

But I wanna like this:
(18,(John, Mary))
(22,(Austin, Sunny))
(78,(Richard, Alice))
(87,(Johnny,))
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

See here: [In Pig latin, am not able to load data as multiple tuples, please advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758022/in-pig-latin-am-not-able-to-load-data-as-multiple-tuples-please-advice)

It's probably worth just having a plain CSV with individual columns.
Then you can load in like:

```
A = LOAD data USING PigStorage(',') AS (age:int, person1:chararray, person2:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE *, (person1, person2) AS couple:tuple(person1:chararray, person2:chararray);
```

Could try changing your load in statement to:

```
A = Load 'data' AS (age:int, couple:tuple(husband:chararray, wife:chararray));
```

Where you're explicitly saying that you want to load in data as a tuple.